# Copy specific worksheets in all active or open workbooks in vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub moveotherschedulesheets()

Set wb1 = Workbooks("A.xlsx")
Dim wbs As Workbooks
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wbs = Application.Workbooks

For Each wb In wbs
    temp = wb.Name
Next
Workbooks("A.xlsx").Activate
With wb1
    Sheets(Array("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", _
        "A6")).Select
    Sheets(Array("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", _
        "A6")).Copy Before:=Workbooks(temp). _
        Worksheets(1)
End With

End Sub
```

In the above-mentioned code, I am trying to paste the selected worksheets("A1,"A2","A3","A4","A5","A6") in all open workbooks at that point of time but this code is giving me wrong output as It is copying selected worksheets in last opened workbook only. Kindly suggest the changes required in the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move

```
For Each wb In wbs
    temp = wb.Name
Next
```

to within

```
With wb1
    ...
End With
```

For instance like this:

```
With wb1
    For Each wb In wbs
        Sheets(Array("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", _
            "A6")).Copy Before:=wb.Worksheets(1)
        Next wb
End With
```

Apart from that, you would probably want to exclude workbook `A.xlsx` as target for this copy action ...